# getting 'cgroup change of group failed' when trying to add process to cgroup

Tags: cgroups

I did the following both on **Ubuntu 14** and **SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)** where libcgroup is installed, with root:

> cgcreate -t ngam:home -a ngam:home -g cpuset:/nadav2ndCpuSet
>
> cgset -r cpuset.cpus=1 nadav2ndCpuSet

After that, if you cat **/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/nadav2ndCpuSet/cpuset.cpus**,
you will get:
1

which is good! as it is supposed to work.

Then, from user **ngam**, I ran the following cmd:

> cgexec -g cpuset:nadav2ndCpuSet ~/whileLoop

where **whileLoop** is just a simple program that runs in a loop doing sqrt.

After that, I got the following error msg:

**cgroup change of group failed**

Why is it happening? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into something similar while playing with cgroups on Ubuntu 16.04 just now.

When using the controller cpuset, cpus and mems are not initiated. Therefor you manually have to do it. Since you already specified cpuset.cpus you only need to set cpuset.mems

simply running

```
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/nadav2ndCpuSet/cpuset.mems
```

or

```
cgset -r cpuset.mems=0 nadav2ndCpuSet
```

would solve your problem.

for more info on cpuset see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html

Comment: Same problem here on Fedora 31 with `Linux 5.5.10-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 18 14:21:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Thanks for sharing Jesper!

Answer (score 0):

What I found is I forgot to make `cgconfig` start with system reboot, so a simple `systemctl start cgconfig` resolve the problem, and then do not forget `systemctl enable cgconfig` to make it start with system reboot.

I know my this answer might not be relevant to the question. I hope when people search the error `cgroup change of group failed`, this answer could help them.

BTW: `systemctl start cgconfig` is for centos 7, for centos 6 you may use `service cgconfig start / chkconfig cgconfig on`